# How can i open panel using dbclick. It should replaced "collapsible: true" i think

Tags: extjs, panel

Below is my panel, i tried to use `itemdblclick` but it does not work.

```
  Ext.define('ExtApp.FilterPanel', {
     extend: 'Ext.Panel',
     alias: 'widget.GridFilterPanel',
     dock: 'top',
     collapsed:true,
     collapsible: true,
     cls: 'extfilter-panel',
     title: 'filters',
     initComponent: function () {
         var self = this
         if (metadataFunc.filtersMetainfo.HasFilter != null) {
           var myTabPanel = metadataFunc.tabPanel;

           self.items = myTabPanel;
           ExtApp.view.refBook.FilterPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
           return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add listeners to header like this:

```
 header : {
     listeners : {
         dblclick : function(header) {
             var panel = header.up('panel');
             if(panel.getCollapsed() ) {
                 panel.expand();
             } else {
                 panel.collapse();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1f5v